# MYSQL_ROW and row[0] to int type

Tags: mysql, c

When using MYSQL C API to query results. The results are returned as a MYSQL_ROW type, which I can easily display using printf("%s", row[0]). But what if I want to assign the contents of row[0] into a int? How can I do that?

Here's a part of the program I am writing.

```
int k = 0;
int sr_nos[1024];
int status;
do {
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if( result == NULL) {
        printf("No Serial no. associated with the tickets");
        printf("stderr: %s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
        break;
    }
    MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    printf("%2s\n", row[0]);

    //store serial no.
    sr_nos[k] = row[0];

    mysql_free_result(result);
    status = mysql_next_result(con);
    if(status > 0) {
        printf("stderr: %s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }
    k++;
} while(status == 0);
```

Comment: Since you are storing MYSQL_ROW type into an integer type array, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`row[0]` is a char * (as MYSQL_ROW is a char **).  If the value is convertible to an int, you can do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
sr_nos[k] = atoi(row[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, from mysql.h:
typedef char \*\*MYSQL_ROW;  /* return data as array of strings */